# How I can I get my home network's IP address from a shell script?

Tags: ssh, ip, ip-address

I have an account at a server at school, and a home computer that I need to work with sometimes. I have exchanged keys, and now only have one problem. While my school account has a name associated with it, "account_name@school", my home network does not. My plan is to have a script that every hour retrieves my home network's IP address, ssh'es into my school account and updates my ssh config file storing my home network's IP address.

How can I retrieve my home computer's IP address from a shell script?

P.S. Is this a sensible plan?

Comment: did you try parsing ipconfig/ifconfig ?

Comment: @alfasin That's unlikely to be useful, as most home networks don't assign public IPs to internal devices.

Comment: @CodeGnome you're right, unless his ISP provided him with a static IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a better way to get the IP address then to use an external service. I am SSHing into the server; therefore, the server must know who is SSHing into it, so I can use a tool like who or pinky to find out who is SSHing in.

Here is the command to get the name of the computer logged in.

```
echo $SSH_CLIENT | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Comment: This doesn't work properly if you are SSH'ed in from another network. If you are on NETWORK A and ssh to a server in NETWORK B, the above command gives the public ip address of NETWORK A instead of the public ip address of the server in NETWORK B.

Comment: @Jakobud getting the IP address of NETWORK A is the point. NETWORK A already knows the IP address of NETWORK B (NETWORK B has a domain name) I wanted NETWORK B to have the IP address of NETWORK A (who doesn't have a domain name) so NETWORK A uses SSH to go tell NETWORK B it's IP address (in this case).

Answer (score 2):

You have two basic choices:

1. A dynamic DNS address (e.g. dyndns.org). Setting that up is outside the scope of Stack Overflow, but it's probably The Right Thing™ for you.
2. Use a tool like http://checkip.dyndns.org/ to report your external IP address, then parse the result.

   ```
   lynx -dump http://checkip.dyndns.org/ | awk '{print $NF}'
   ```

Either way, you'll need to configure your router to allow inbound access for SSH, so further information needs to be asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: you're right (+1), and googling "what is my IP" also works ;)

Answer (score 1):

My http://ipcalf.com server supports header-based or explicit content negotiation, which is a fancy way of saying that if you `curl -H Accept:text/plain ipcalf.com` or `curl -s http://ipcalf.com/?format=text` you should get your public IP address in raw form.

("Full" documentation and source code are [on github](https://github.com/natevw/ipcalf).)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a request to http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp to fetch your public IP from [WIMI](http://www.whatismyip.com/). This command:

```
ssh account_name@school "echo -n "$(wget http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp -O -)" > some_remote_file"
```

will write your home public IP to a file called "some_remote_file" in your home folder at school. Set it up with cron and you will have access to your home's routers public IP from your school.

If you've already set up some sort of port forwarding on your router so that you can ssh to your home computer with the routers IP, you should be good to go :)